Problem with author display in compiling a journal volume with multiple articles
I'm trying to compile a full journal volume that includes several articles, notes, and news sections. The structure is standard, with Titles, Authors, Affiliations, ORCIDs, Abstracts, and References. I'm using \documentclass[journal]{paper} and the \refsection environment to manage individual references for each article.
Project struture
main.tex
CG.sty
articles/
   article01
   article02
   ...
bibliographies/
images/

After setting everything up, the PDF compiles successfully, but there's an issue: the authors are displayed only in the first article and not in the subsequent ones. I suspect the author command needs to be reset between articles, but all attempts to fix this have been unsuccessful.
Suspected Issue in CG.sty:
The problem seems related to the \@author\par command in the style file. It correctly displays the authors for the first article but does not repeat for subsequent ones.
\AtBeginDocument{
  \renewcommand{\@maketitle}{% 
    \ifdefined\HCode\else
    \fi
    \noindent\begin{minipage}{0.9\linewidth}
    \raggedright\setstretch{1.0}
    {\LARGE\bfseries{\@title}\par}
    \vskip 0.5em 
    {\printothertitles{\thecntothertitle}}
    \vskip\baselineskip
    \@author\par 
    \end{minipage}\bigskip\normalfont\normalsize%
  }
}

Minimal working example
Below is a minimal working example of the main file, demonstrating the issue. The first article's authors display correctly, but the second article's do not.
\documentclass[journal,noindent,heading]{paper}
\usepackage{CG}  
\usepackage{import}

\begin{document}

\journalpart[ARTIGOS]{}

\begin{refsection}
\shortauthor{Author AA, Author BB}
\title{Title for Article 01}
\author[1]{Author AA}
\author[2]{Author BB}
\affil[1]{Affiliation one}
\affil[2]{Affiliation two}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum 
\end{refsection}

\begin{refsection}
\shortauthor{Author CC}
\title{Title for Article 02}
\author[1]{Author CC}
\affil[1]{Affiliation three}
\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum dolor 
\end{refsection}

\end{document}


Everything else (abstracts, sections, bibliographies, etc.) works fine, but the author list does not appear after the first article.
I believe the issue lies in resetting the author environment between articles, but I haven't been able to resolve it. I would greatly appreciate any guidance or suggestions.
Thank you in advance, and apologies if this request is lacking in any way. Please let me know if more details are needed.
